# Extract raw text from rtf file

Tags: java, text, apache-poi, apache-tika, text-extraction

Once upon a time I was using apache POI to extract rtf files. I was actually using the TXTParser class because then I could use the raw output from the rtf (with all the formatting in text) to do various text extraction wizadry based on the formatting.

Then one day it just started to output blank strings and I have no idea why.

```
public class TextParser {
//@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public TextParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException,TikaException{
 //detecting the file type
 BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

 FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/PhysJava/dance.rtf"));
 ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
 //Text document parser
 TXTParser TXTParser = new TXTParser();
 try {
     TXTParser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);

} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
 //Some tidying up
 String s=handler.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the file because if I use another class (ie `RTFParser`) I get the whole file.
`HtmlParser` would be an alternative but only gives me half the file returned.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to get the rtf as required or a fix for this weird problem

Comment: `http://www.emreakkas.com/localization-tools/convert-rtf-to-txt`

Comment: Looking for java code really

Comment: Why not just use `AutoDetectParser` and let Tika figure out the right parser for you?

Comment: Because I rely on seeing the formatting for the downstream code and Tika would just choose the RTFParser for RTF files and not give me the formatting